# Connecting laptops through ssh and adding hosts to laptop

Tags: ssh, mpi, host, ssh-keys

I want to make an MPI cluster between two laptops. So I need to connect it via ssh. I am following this link: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster
for accomplishing it.
But before that I need to add the other laptop's IP address to my known hosts. When I googled it I got know that I need to manually edit the /etc/hosts file (like doing in a text editor) with super user permission. But I'm apprehensive about changing it manually. Can someone tell how to add hosts so that I can proceed with my project.

Here are my contents of /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   shabhri-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Unlike some configuration files (like `/etc/sudoers`), you can't really break anything with an error in `/etc/hosts`. At worst, you'll get the wrong IP address for a particular host, and you can simply delete the offending line or edit it. As with anything, it's always a good idea to make a backup of the file before editing.

Answer (score 1):

You just add your new hosts with their IP addresses at the end of the first section. So it will look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   shabhri-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC
192.168.0.2 otherlaptop
192.168.0.3 laptopnumber3
...etc...

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: and one more thing when I was going through the link it said I shouldnt have 127.0.1.1 - <my pc name> otherwise other hosts will try to connect to localhost when they try to reach <my pc name>. So I should just go and remove it and put my ip address instead of 127.0.1.1 ?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise your other hosts won't be able to connect.

Comment: im sorry for asking again but I should just manually change the file and no other configuration is required?? I really want to be very sure before doing it.

Comment: You probably have to use whatever other steps are in the instructions that you're using. I've never used those instructions so I can't say how good or bad they are.

Answer (score 0):

just simply open the host file with your favorite text editor and add the entry of your connected host (Host IP space hostname) in host file to the end of the file.

no need to worry about hosts